# Undo drawing in Paint Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es, undo-redo

I am making a paint application using OpenGl framework and I'm stuck at UNDO/REDO option..
The code I implemented is like this:

```
  -(void)undo_called
{

artbrushAppDelegate *app=(artbrushAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
mbrushscale=app.brushscale;
brushimage=app.brush_image;
Erase=YES;
[self playRayundo];
 }


-(void)playRayundo
{
artbrushAppDelegate *app=(artbrushAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
glColor4f(app.r1g,
          app.b1g,
          app.g1g,
          0);
NSLog(@"%f",app.r1g);


if(undo != NULL)
{
    for(int l = 0; l < [undo count]; l++)
    {
        //replays my writRay -1 because of location point
        for(int p = 0; p < [[undo objectAtIndex:l]count]-1; p ++)
        {
            [self drawErase:[[[undo objectAtIndex:l]objectAtIndex:p]CGPointValue] toPoint:[[[undo objectAtIndex:l]objectAtIndex:p + 1]CGPointValue]];
        }
    }
}

Erase=NO;
glColor4f(app.rg,
          app.bg,
          app.gg,
          kBrushOpacity);

  }



 -(void) drawErase:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end

 {
    static GLfloat*     eraseBuffer = NULL;
    static NSUInteger   eraseMax = 64;

NSUInteger          vertexCount = 0,
count,
i;

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);

// Convert locations from Points to Pixels
CGFloat scale = 1.0;//self.contentScaleFactor;
start.x *= scale;
start.y *= scale;
end.x *= scale;
end.y *= scale;

// Allocate vertex array buffer
if(eraseBuffer == NULL)
    eraseBuffer = malloc(eraseMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));

// Add points to the buffer so there are drawing points every X pixels      
count = MAX(ceilf(sqrtf((end.x - start.x) * (end.x - start.x) + (end.y - start.y) * (end.y - start.y)) / kBrushPixelStep), 1);

for(i = 0; i < count; ++i) 
{
    if(vertexCount == eraseMax) 
    {
        eraseMax = 2 * eraseMax;
        eraseBuffer = realloc(eraseBuffer, eraseMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));
    }

    eraseBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 0] = start.x + (end.x - start.x) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
    eraseBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 1] = start.y + (end.y - start.y) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
    vertexCount += 1;
  }

  [self ChangebrushPic:brushimage];

 //the erase brush color  is transparent.

glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES);
glTexEnvf(GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES, GL_COORD_REPLACE_OES, GL_TRUE);
glPointSize(64/mbrushscale);

// Render the vertex array

glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, eraseBuffer);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);


// Display the buffer
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];

// at last restore the  mixed-mode
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

 }
```

This code is not efficient and it has so many faults..Have a look at images before and After Undo.

Before: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/577/screenshot20110714at121.png/

After: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/200/screenshot20110714at121.png/

So i want to Save image in buffer every time user's Touch ends and call previous image on UNDO..Can anyone help me how to Store image in buffer and retrieve back on UNDO?? I tried to find its sample code but could not find..

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I am posting answer to my own Question as so many people seem to refer this question.

There is an application named **TouchPainter** and its [source code](http://www.apress.com/apple-mac/objective-c/9781430233305) is available. It contains drawing, color blending, Undo/Redo (Amazing..!!), Save/Open drawings..

**Note :** It may require very deep level knowledge of **Objective C** and **design pattern** (I still do not know what design pattern is. But I found it so I am sharing..). The whole application's source code is explained in this book **"Apress.Pro Objective-C Design Patterns for iOS"**.

I hope it will be helpful to you.. :) Good luck..

Comment: TouchPainter is not a drawing Application based on OpenGL ES. Check twice .

Comment: @Mustafa: Thanks.. Generally its a bad idea to provide just links in answers but i did not get any correct answer for few months and came across this Application sample code so I thought I should just post link to it so visitor at least gets the correct direction.. :-))

Comment: @Mustafa : Please provide answer here if you solve this Undo issue. :-)) I would be happy to accept it as an answer.

Comment: I'm drawing using Quartz 2D/Core Graphics. For each draw operation i.e. drawing a line, rectangle, an arc; I save the path (UIBezierPath) in an NSMutableArray. Then for undo/redo, i use this array to redraw the whole content (the required UIBezierPath(s)).

Comment: Whereas, TouchPainter is using UndoManager, which is probably a better idea.

Comment: Very old pattern of drawing... It can causes memory warning. If you build app for iPad using this technique your app will be crashed. Check the total memory usage by clicking "command+i" after opening the project.

Answer (score 0):

use the nsundomanager, that is the best way to undo

Comment: NSUndoManager isn't magic -- it can help you manage undo state, but actually implementing undo in your model is still up to you.

Comment: Someone told me to use command pattern for it.. will that method be useful??

Comment: @anonymous do you have the sample code for Undo/Redo Function in GLpaint ? I need a start

Answer (score 0):

```
        Hope this may be help u..

This code for UIBezierPath Drawing.

    -(void)undoButtonClicked
        {
            if([pathArray count]>0){
                UIBezierPath *_path = [pathArray lastObject];
                [bufferArray addObject:_path];
                [bufferColorArray addObject:[PathColorArray lastObject]];
                [pathArray removeLastObject];
                [PathColorArray removeLastObject];
                [bufferDrawType addObject:[pathDrawType lastObject]];
                [pathDrawType removeLastObject];
                [bufferDrawOpacity addObject:[pathDrawOpacity lastObject]];
                [pathDrawOpacity removeLastObject];
                [bufferDrawLineWidth addObject:[pathDrawLineWidth lastObject]];
                [pathDrawLineWidth removeLastObject];

                [self setNeedsDisplay];
            }
        }

        -(void)redoButtonClicked
        {
            if([bufferArray count]>0){
                UIBezierPath *_path = [bufferArray lastObject];
                [pathArray addObject:_path];
                [bufferArray removeLastObject];
                [PathColorArray addObject:[bufferColorArray lastObject]];
                [bufferColorArray removeLastObject];
                [pathDrawType addObject:[bufferDrawType lastObject]];
                [bufferDrawType removeLastObject];

                [pathDrawOpacity addObject:[bufferDrawOpacity lastObject]];
                [bufferDrawOpacity removeLastObject];
                [pathDrawLineWidth addObject:[bufferDrawLineWidth lastObject]];
                [bufferDrawLineWidth removeLastObject];

                [self setNeedsDisplay];
            }
        }
```